# PHP PDO - could not find driver but driver is installed and enabled

Tags: php, pdo

I have PHP7.2 (apache) running on my local Ubuntu 16 machine. All my applications were working until yesterday when I tried to connect to my GSQL database. I had already been successfully connecting and sending INSERT statements all day until I got the error "could not find driver". So something seems to have changed.

Here is my phpinfo():

[Screenshot from my phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FPbm.png)

Here is the code Im using to connect. The only thing that has changed is that Im now trying to connect with the SSL options. I have the certificate files stored locally in a directory above my doc root. I tried both with and without the SSL options and I still get the same error.

```
//Connect to the DB
$this->connection = new PDO("
    mysql:host=$this->servername;
    dbname=$this->database",$this->u,$this->p,[
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => $this->ck,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   => $this->cc,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => $this->sc,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
    ]
);
$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Ive tried all sorts of different solutions from the google and stack search results to no avail.

Comment: Is there a more complete error message…?

Comment: You mention a [GSQL database](https://docs.tigergraph.com/dev/gsql-ref), which seems to be something that exists, yet you use MySQL in your connection and you also show this in your `phpinfo()` image. Which is it?

Comment: The complete error messgage is as stated - could not find driver. 
GSQL is Google Cloud SSL.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have answered your question, do you have anything further to add?

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen your previous comment. The @ helped to draw my attention to your second comment. First of all: I have no experience with Google Cloud SSL, and its associated [GSQL database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl). I do however know how you can [test which drivers are present for PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php). Simply use: `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`. MySQL should be there.

Comment: I've also notice you're using spaces and returns in your [PDO DSN](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php). I don't know if this is allowed, but I would try a DSN without spaces and returns.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, These are the available drivers. `Array ( [0] => mysql )`. The spaces and returns wont make a difference.

Comment: You said: _"The spaces and returns wont make a difference."_, that does somewhat imply you didn't take the small effort of actually testing this. I'll strengthen my case. Read [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). You will encounter the boldly written sentence: **"no spaces or quotes or other decorations have to be used in DSN"**. I realize this could be read as: "but you are allowed to", but why not give it a try?

Comment: As you say its the DSN that applies to, where as I was looking at the options array. I thought I posted my own answer to this but hasnt saved. I will update now.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to @KIKO Software for helping me with this and pointing me at my error. Can't thank you enough.

The error was breaking the DSN onto multiple lines.

```
//Connect to the DB
$this->connection = new PDO("
  mysql:host=$this->servername;dbname=$this->database",$this->u,$this->p,[
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => $this->ck,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   => $this->cc,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => $this->sc,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
  ]  
);
$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```